# How to pass tumblr api GDPR info and get JSON?

Tags: swift, api, tumblr

When I request api http://demo.tumblr.com/api/read/json I get html with GDPR info instead of json. On website I can just simply click "ok" and then I get json, how to do it properly in swift?

```
    func makeReq(){
    let url = "http://demo.tumblr.com/api/read/json"

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { data, response, error in

        let html = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        self.webView.loadHTMLString(html!, baseURL: nil)

        }.resume()
}
```

Comment: @Moritz Right, but I've done it(on my private account). "demo" in url is user.  I have tried to open html in webView and catch link after click "Ok" button but there is no action.

Comment: This looks to be fixed: http://demo.tumblr.com/api/read/json

Comment: @mikedidthis Try it in postman and then you will see my problem. In web browser after click "ok" you will get json but problem is how to do same thing on mobile doing request? :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with the Swift, but to get past the GDPR consent page, you need to send a cookie named 'pfg' whose content depends of the user-agent string sent with the request.  These are the steps I followed:

1. In Chrome, use .../More tools/Developer tools to open the debugger, then .../More tools/Network conditions.  Here you can set the user-agent string sent by Chrome to anything you want.  I chose XXXXX for brevity.
2. Browse to demo.tumblr.com/read/api and get the consent form.  Click OK.
3. Use the Chrome cookies.txt extension to save the cookies for the site to a text file.  You can pick out the lengthy 'pfg' cookie later.
4. Make your program send the user-agent string XXXXX and the 'pfg' cookie with the request.  You can try it out with

   `wget -U XXXXX --load-cookies=cookies.txt https://demo.tumblr.com/read/api`
5. The expiry for the cookie is set to 12 months.  Perhaps you will need to renew it before then, or perhaps not.  Who knows?

Comment: This answer is now obsolete in the context of the new Tumblr API.